# How to easily hide all content and display a message for mobile devices on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this very basic todo list app. (http://www.hackerpup.com/todo/index.html) It was really just an intro project to practice jQuery. I'm happy with the result however, it is very ugly on mobile devices and until I reconfigure it to look okay on mobile I'd like it to not be available on mobile devices.

Is there an easy way to hide all the content on my page and just display a simple message instead for mobile devices? Even as simple as text saying "Sorry this page is not made for mobile devices".

(I'm happy to do this with css, javascript/jquery or anything that will work).

Thanks

Comment: Serious question for you to ponder: what is a "mobile device"? My laptop can use 3G, but probably isn't despite being portable and using a phone network. My 10" android tablet might count as a mobile device, but it has a keyboard dock, and I bet your content will work just fine on it. My Nexus 5 has a higher resolution than the 10" tablet, but I bet your app will be horrible on it. "Mobile device" is not a real thing, at least not when you're programming: figure out what you *really* need in terms of minimum requirements, then see if you can detect those.

Comment: I just meant anything under 768px

Comment: High, or wide? Regardless, you should edit your question to make that information explicit (so people don't have go through the comment thread to find the most important information)

Answer (score 1):

In your link you have been using bootstrap, so you can easily solve your problem by bootstrap

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
        <div>My all element </div>
</div>
<div class="visible-xs">
       <p>My Text </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I had originally posted some CSS, but since you are already using BootStrap, Alimon's suggestion makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're utilizing Bootstrap, you can use its [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes):

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    <!-- your original HTML that will be hidden when screen width is <768px -->
</div>
<div class="visible-xs-block"> <!-- 'visible-xs' was deprecated as of Bootstrap 3.2.0 and I see that you are using 3.3.5 -->
    Sorry this page is not made for mobile devices
</div>
```

**Anyway**, this is not the best solution. You should just continue to allow users to continue using your site *even* with a mobile web browser ;-)